# Convert five lines of Mootools to jQuery

Tags: jquery, mootools

Can someone please help me out with this? I'm using jquery-1.4.2.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ymkpb/

Thank you so much!

*Edit - Adding the original so this is more useful later:*

```
$$('.clickables').each(function(clickable) {
    var list = clickable.getElements('li');

    list.addEvent('click', function() {
        var link = this.getElement('a');
        if(this.getFirst('a')) {
            window.location = link
        }
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would look like this in jQuery:

```
$('.clickables li').click(function() {
  window.location = $(this).children('a').attr('href');
});​
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Ymkpb/7/)

Comment: @Daniel O'Connor: Don't forget to mark this as the correct answer :)